# ReduxToolkit [TS]: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft<CounterState>'

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit first time with typescript. I have a Redux State like this:

```
export interface CounterState {
  id: string;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
  email: string;
  password:string;
}
```

And a reducer like this:

```
reducers: {
    updateField: (state,action:PayloadAction<updateFieldObject>)=> {
        const {fieldName,value} = action.payload;
        state[fieldName as keyof updateFieldObject] = value;
        //Tried all 3 variants
        //state[fieldName as keyof typeof updateFieldObject] = value;
        //state[fieldName] = value;
    },
}
```

From the above expression, The problem I am trying to solve is to pass a string and then use it to update the state expression.

But it gives follwoing error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft<CounterState>'.
```

**Update 1: Complete Code and Tried using KeyOf**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState, AppThunk } from '../../app/store';


export interface CounterState {
  id: string;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
  email: string;
  password:string;
}

interface updateFieldObject {
    fieldName: string;
    value: string;
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  id: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  status: 'idle',
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userInfo',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    updateField: (state,action:PayloadAction<updateFieldObject>)=> {
        const {fieldName,value} = action.payload;
        state[fieldName as keyof updateFieldObject] = value;
    },

    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
  },
  // The `extraReducers` field lets the slice handle actions defined elsewhere,
  // including actions generated by createAsyncThunk or in other slices.
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementAsync.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(incrementAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.value += action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

// The function below is called a selector and allows us to select a value from
// the state. Selectors can also be defined inline where they're used instead of
// in the slice file. For example: `useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter.value)`
export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.counter.value;

// We can also write thunks by hand, which may contain both sync and async logic.
// Here's an example of conditionally dispatching actions based on current state.
export const incrementIfOdd =
  (amount: number): AppThunk =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const currentValue = selectCount(getState());
    if (currentValue % 2 === 1) {
      dispatch(incrementByAmount(amount));
    }
  };

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Please provide the complete code. What's your state slice and `updateFieldObject` type looks like?

Comment: @slideshowp2 have added. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Your `updateFieldObject` interface has `fieldName` and `value` fields, while your state, `CounterState`, doesn't have `fieldName` nor `value` fields. The TS error is telling you that you can't assign a value to `state['fieldName']`, nor `state['value']`. If you're sure that `fieldName` is of type `keyof CounterState`, then cast `fieldName` as `keyof CounterState` instead: `state[fieldName as keyof CounterState]`

Comment: Another solution, instead of casting, would be to change the `fieldName` type of `updateFieldObject` interface to `fieldName: keyof CounterState`. If that's what you're trying to accomplish here

Comment: Hmm using this I am getting: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"idle" | "loading" | "failed"'.